# Faster way to update dataframe rows after group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

### Sample Input:

```
    GAME_ID     TIME    PER EVENT
0   0022000394  12:00   1   12
1   0022000394  12:00   1   10
2   0022000394  11:36   1   1
3   0022000394  11:24   1   1
4   0022000394  11:04   1   1
5   0022000394  10:41   1   1
6   0022000394  10:30   1   2
7   0022000394  10:29   1   4
8   0022000394  10:17   1   1
9   0022000394  10:01   1   1
10  0022000394  9:48    1   2
11  0022000394  9:46    1   4
12  0022000394  9:42    1   6
13  0022000394  9:42    1   3
14  0022000394  9:42    1   3
15  0022000394  9:25    1   1
16  0022000394  9:15    1   1
17  0022000394  9:15    1   6
18  0022000394  9:15    1   3
19  0022000394  8:53    1   1
20  0022000394  8:33    1   1
21  0022000394  8:22    1   1
22  0022000394  8:16    1   2
23  0022000394  8:16    1   4
24  0022000394  8:12    1   2
```

I have a dataframe where I get a group of rows using `groupby`.

If that group contains 3 rows where the column `EVENTMSGTYPE` contains all of `[1, 6, & 3]` I want to update the row in the original dataframe where `EVENTMSGTYPE == 1`

### Current Working Solution (Slow)

```py
# Group by
for _, data in df.groupby(['GAME_ID', 'TIME', 'PER']):

    # If EVENT in group contains 1, 6, and 3 then update original df
    if all(x in list(data.EVENT) for x in [1, 6, 3]):

        # Update original df row where EVENT equals 1, should only have one value
        index = data[data.EVENT == 1].index.values[0]

        # Set UPDATED to True
        df.at[index, 'UPDATED'] = True
```

Expected Output:

```
    GAME_ID     TIME    PER EVENT UPDATED
...
16  0022000394  9:15    1   1     True
...
```

My dataframe has 1,694,389 rows and this takes ~53 seconds to run on my machine, can the performance of this be improved?

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframe, with expected output

Comment: this guide has some good tips for creating dummy data that behaves like your problem: [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Apologies, I have added a sample dataframe @sammywemmy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['UPDATED'] = df.groupby(['GAME_ID', 'TIME', 'PER'])['EVENT'].filter(lambda x: set(x) >= {1,3,6}, dropna=False).eq(1)
```

Output:

```
     GAME_ID   TIME  PER  EVENT  UPDATED
0   22000394  12:00    1     12    False
1   22000394  12:00    1     10    False
2   22000394  11:36    1      1    False
3   22000394  11:24    1      1    False
4   22000394  11:04    1      1    False
5   22000394  10:41    1      1    False
6   22000394  10:30    1      2    False
7   22000394  10:29    1      4    False
8   22000394  10:17    1      1    False
9   22000394  10:01    1      1    False
10  22000394   9:48    1      2    False
11  22000394   9:46    1      4    False
12  22000394   9:42    1      6    False
13  22000394   9:42    1      3    False
14  22000394   9:42    1      3    False
15  22000394   9:25    1      1    False
16  22000394   9:15    1      1     True
17  22000394   9:15    1      6    False
18  22000394   9:15    1      3    False
19  22000394   8:53    1      1    False
20  22000394   8:33    1      1    False
21  22000394   8:22    1      1    False
22  22000394   8:16    1      2    False
23  22000394   8:16    1      4    False
24  22000394   8:12    1      2    False
```

Stole the set logic from sammywemmy~

Comment: doesn't match expected output

Comment: Only row 16 should be `True`

Comment: The original without the set logic takes a lot longer than the original solution

Comment: Using the set logic this is much faster, 16 seconds on my machine

Comment: Why do you use ">=" instead of "=="?

Comment: @Drakax Because, for example: `{1,3,6,8} >= {1,3,6}` is `True`, but `{1,3,6,8} == {1,3,6}` is `False`

Comment: Ok thank you :) Could you please try if this one is faster "df['UPDATED'] = df.groupby(['GAME_ID', 'TIME', 'PER'])['EVENT'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= {1,3,6} and x == 1)"? And I was wondering if we could have used "df.groupby(['GAME_ID', 'TIME', 'PER'])['EVENT'].unique().???" somehow?

Comment: I couldn't tell you why, but the `transform` method is far slower than the `filter` method on the test dataset. Also, `unique()` and `set()` are very similar in the type of result they produce, but `set()` will have a lot less bloat.

Answer (score 2):

One option is using `set` with transform; speed wise I expect Bert2ME's solution to be faster:

```py
df.assign(UPDATED = df.groupby(grouper)
                      .EVENT
                      .transform(lambda x: set(x) >= {1,3,6}) 
                                           & df.EVENT.eq(1))

     GAME_ID   TIME  PER  EVENT  UPDATED
0   22000394  12:00    1     12    False
1   22000394  12:00    1     10    False
2   22000394  11:36    1      1    False
3   22000394  11:24    1      1    False
4   22000394  11:04    1      1    False
5   22000394  10:41    1      1    False
6   22000394  10:30    1      2    False
7   22000394  10:29    1      4    False
8   22000394  10:17    1      1    False
9   22000394  10:01    1      1    False
10  22000394   9:48    1      2    False
11  22000394   9:46    1      4    False
12  22000394   9:42    1      6    False
13  22000394   9:42    1      3    False
14  22000394   9:42    1      3    False
15  22000394   9:25    1      1    False
16  22000394   9:15    1      1     True
17  22000394   9:15    1      6    False
18  22000394   9:15    1      3    False
19  22000394   8:53    1      1    False
20  22000394   8:33    1      1    False
21  22000394   8:22    1      1    False
22  22000394   8:16    1      2    False
23  22000394   8:16    1      4    False
24  22000394   8:12    1      2    False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
idx_cols = ['GAME_ID', 'TIME', 'PER']

df = df.set_index(idx_cols)

cond1 = (
    df.groupby(level=idx_cols)['EVENT']
      .agg(lambda event_group: all(x in event_group for x in [1, 6, 3])) 
      .reindex_like(df)
)

cond2 = df['EVENT'].eq(1)

df['UPDATED'] = cond1 & cond2

df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     GAME_ID   TIME  PER  EVENT  UPDATED
0   22000394  12:00    1     12    False
1   22000394  12:00    1     10    False
2   22000394  11:36    1      1    False
3   22000394  11:24    1      1    False
4   22000394  11:04    1      1    False
5   22000394  10:41    1      1    False
6   22000394  10:30    1      2    False
7   22000394  10:29    1      4    False
8   22000394  10:17    1      1    False
9   22000394  10:01    1      1    False
10  22000394   9:48    1      2    False
11  22000394   9:46    1      4    False
12  22000394   9:42    1      6    False
13  22000394   9:42    1      3    False
14  22000394   9:42    1      3    False
15  22000394   9:25    1      1    False
16  22000394   9:15    1      1     True
17  22000394   9:15    1      6    False
18  22000394   9:15    1      3    False
19  22000394   8:53    1      1    False
20  22000394   8:33    1      1    False
21  22000394   8:22    1      1    False
22  22000394   8:16    1      2    False
23  22000394   8:16    1      4    False
24  22000394   8:12    1      2    False
```

Comment: Apologies, I have added a sample dataframe

Comment: `ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names` on line `df.loc[cond1 & cond2, 'UPDATED'] = True`

Comment: @radio23 it should work now. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: I don't think this is the right output

Comment: @sammywemmy what am I missing then? :p

Comment: it has to contain all three to be True, not just one of them

Comment: ohhh of course... I see now, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Correct I think the `isin([1, 3, 6])` is causing issues

Comment: give me a minute

Comment: @radio23 I think now it's correct

Comment: @radio23 Can you benchmark it against your solution and see if it's a good improvement? I'm curious

Comment: It takes ~38 seconds on my machine but I don't get any values set to `True`